# When the Salesforce Survey is submitted using the link, how do we get the ORG Base URL using Record Triggered flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, url

**My implementation:** Implemented a flow, triggered when someone submits a Salesforce Survey. The Survey Link is sent to the user using email. I need the org URL to generate a Record Link in the flow. That record link will be used elsewhere.

**Current Formula:**  I am currently using this formula field on the flow, and it was working fine(Imagine the company name is X):

```
LEFT($Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_510, FIND( '/services', $Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_510)) & {!$Record.Id}
```

**Generated URL:**

```
x-test.sandbox.lightning.force.com/RecordId
```

**What issue am I facing currently?** I'm not sure if Salesforce changed something with the new release! Today, I tested it, and it is not giving me the org base URL and maybe the partner portal URL.

`x-test.sandbox.my.site.com/XPartnerPortalLightningOne/RecordId`. ,

I created the formula both in the flow and as a custom field. However, the results are the same as mentioned above.

Comment: Survey invitation link URLS are associated with an Experience Cloud site